# best way to filter data from user(xss and sql injection)

Tags: php, xss, sql-injection

I read a lot about filtering data which my web site get from user to make web site secure in sql injenction and xss . . .
but I saw a lot function in php so I can't make decide what to do . . .
please help me make it more secure

Comment: Securing data always depends on what you are doing with it in your code. You'll need to ask a specific question about that, possibly with some code

Answer (score 6):

You're asking a couple questions here, so I'll try to break it down:

### SQL Injection

#### Problem

This can occur when you pass user input directly to the database, something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field = " . $_POST['field'];
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

The user can put whatever they want into the 'field' field on the form, and the database will execute it. This means a user could enter a malicious string which prematurely terminates your intended query and then runs a query of their own.

#### Solution

Don't directly construct your queries with user input. Instead, you should look into using prepared statements (This is typically handled with the [PDO](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) library). Prepared statements can take several forms, but they all involve using placeholders in the actual query string to tell the database where to stick other data you'll pass in later. That way the database can handle any appropriate escaping itself. The code would look a bit like this:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE field = :field");
$statement->bindValue(":field", $_GET['field']);
$statement->execute();
```

In this case, `:field` indicates the placeholder for the value later supplied by `bindValue`. PDO will take care of the escaping as needed.

That said, you should still sanitize any user data as needed.

### XSS

#### Problem

Cross-Site Scripting, or XSS, occurs when unsanitized user input is passed directly back to the browser. If the user entered JavaScript commands, these commands could be executed in another users browser, possibly allowing the original hacker to gain access to that users credentials.

#### Solution

Rather than going into a lot of detail here, I'll simply say that this can be avoided by setting the HttpOnly flag on any cookies you set, so that they cannot be accessed in JavaScript (malicious or otherwise), and by never, *ever* echoing back unsanitized inputs to a user.

### Sanitizing User Inputs

PHP has some nice features built in for sanitizing many forms of user input. I'll simply recommend that you check out the [`filter_var` function](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and the [various filters](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php) it can apply.

Never just echo user input back to the user. You should do your best to validate your inputs and reject anything that doesn't conform, but for inputs you need to display back to the user, always use something like [`htmlentities()`](http://ca.php.net/htmlentities). For a heavier but much more thorough option, you can take a look at the [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) library.

Hope that gets you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Most SQL injections can be prevented with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, assuming you're running MySQL. Other database systems also have similar functions.

Protecting your site from XSS attacks is more complicated. The simplest way to prevent javascript code injection is stripping away all HTML tags with `strip_tags()`, but that will prevent using harmless tags like `<b>` as well, though they can be whitelisted if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The only generic advice I can give you is to learn:

Prepared statements to avoid **SQL injections**

A custom markup languages like StackOverflow is using to avoid **XSS attacks**